# Why pandas silently ignores .iloc[i, j] assignment with too many indices?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does pandas behave differently when setting or getting items in a series with erroneous number of indexes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10]})
# df['a'] is a series, can be indexed with 1 index only

# will raise IndexingError, as expected
df['a'].iloc[0, 0]
df['a'].loc[0, 0]

# will raise nothing, not as expected
df['a'].iloc[0, 0] = 1000 # equivalent to pass
df['a'].loc[0, 0] = 1000 # equivalent to df['a'].loc[0] = 1000

# pandas version 0.18.1, python 3.5
```

Edit: [Reported](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13831).

Comment: Perhaps the `df['a'].iloc` object overrides the `__setattr__` and/or `__setitem__` functions, which allows objects to specify different behavior when setting a value.  But in the first example you aren't _setting_ the value, you're just _referencing_ it, so there isn't any overridden function to call, and it uses the default Python list behavior, which produces the error.

Comment: @JohnGordon shouldn't the overridden behavior in the "setting a value" case be to produce an error instead of silently doing nothing?

Comment: I misinterpreted your question.  I thought the first example was getting the standard Python error when you try to access a normal list with a tuple subscript instead of an integer.  But that's a `TypeError`, not a `IndexingError`, so I was wrong.  No idea why Pandas lets you do the second one.

Comment: It must be a bug. Or are you asking what is exactly happening under the hood?

Comment: @ptrj I assumed it's not a bug because it would be too obvious, and .loc .iloc indexing is relatively mature in pandas. But if it's a bug, I'll just report it on github.

Comment: df['a'].iloc[0, False] = 1000  ---> could it be 0 as False.

Comment: @Merlin what would [0, False] mean?

Comment: This is really about `Series` since `df['a']` is a `Series` (you get the same behavior).

Comment: @max There are many surprising bugs in pandas. It's worth reporting. Even if `loc[x, y]` is not a bug (it behaves like `.loc[[x, y]]`), the behaviour of `.iloc[x, y]` is inconsistent.

Comment: Apparently, this bug was introduced rather recently. On my machine at work, still pandas `0.14.1` is installed and there the last two lines of your example also faile with an IndexingError.

Comment: On my personal machine, though, a newer pandas version can reproduce the strange behavior. I guess multiple indices at least in `loc` are interpreted as a list. At least for me you could do something like `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3]})` and then `df['a'].loc[0, 1, 0] = [10, 11, 12]` would result in `df` holding `12, 11` afterwards. It still silently fails for `iloc`, though. I also think that this is a bug that should be reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Getting values

If the key is a tuple (as in your example), then the `__getitem__` method of the superclass for the `loc` and `iloc` objects at some point calls `_has_valid_tuple(self, key)`.

This method has the following code

```
for i, k in enumerate(key):
    if i >= self.obj.ndim:
        raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
```

This raises an `IndexingError` you would expect.

#### Setting values

The superclass's `__setitem__` makes a call to `_get_setitem_indexer` and in turn `_convert_to_indexer`.

This superclass's implementation of `_convert_to_indexer` is a bit messy but in this case it returns a numpy array `[0, 0]`.

The class of the iLoc indexer, however, overrides `_convert_to_indexer`. This method returns the original tuple...

```
def _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis=0, is_setter=False):
    ...
    elif self._has_valid_type(obj, axis):
        return obj
```

Now an `indexer` variable is a numpy array for the `.loc` case and tuple for the `.iloc` case. This causes the difference in setting behavior in the subsequent superclass call to `_setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)`.

Comment: I guess it should be fixed to always raise an error, both for loc and iloc?

Comment: Yea that check that is made when setting values would seem to be a good candidate... Maybe one of the core pandas developers has some insight into why there is all of these different behaviors. The pandas dev forums would be a good place to post this.